# How to override notify from another recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to know how to override a notify service from another recipe (chef wrapper). For example, I have a recipe A where i have defined all the service start and stop. I want override these notify from RecipeB.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to put this service in its own recipe, so that you can include simply it in RecipeA, but not in RecipeB.

Alternatively, and this is a hack, you can simply add another `service` section to RecipeB, and ensure it is stopped again (`action [:disable, :stop]`). This is not ideal, however, as it will result in the service being turned on toward the beginning of every run, and then turned off again at the end.

Comment: This doest work in my case. Solution what am looking is , I have a Recipe A, Where all the service start stop happens and i dont have access to modify Recipe A cookbook, Hence i decided to write my own wrapper to manage RecipeA services. I need a help to set Notify delayed from Recipe B.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean by "all the service start stop." It's also unclear if "Notify" (capitalized) is the name of a specific service/daemon or something else. Perhaps specific code would make it easier to understand what you're asking.

Comment: . I have Receipe A which has Apache installation and configuration and same recipe has httpd service restart. Now i have to add some conf file to apache directory and restart apache service from Recipe B.

Comment: If all you're trying to do in RecipeB is to reload the Apache configuration, then simply using the `:reload` action in `service` resource in RecipeB will be enough, and won't cause a restart (and therefore no downtime).

Answer (score 0):

You just do it. Nothing about notifications is scoped to cookbooks. All you need to know is the type and name of the target resource.